# Regex replace format template with a string so that the result is a formatted string

Tags: php, c++, regex, templates, string-formatting

Basically I have the following:

- input string (eg ABCDEFGHI)
- input template (eg XXX-XXX-XXX)

and the output I want to see is `ABC-DEF-GHI`

I imagine it going something like `"XXX-XXX-XXX".replace("regex", "ABCDEFGHI");`

The catch is that the template is dynamic. It may be `XXX-XXX-XXX` or `XX-XXXX-XXX` or any other combination that can include any special character but the charater to match is always `X`.

The template is not limited in length or number of groups separated by special characters.
i.e. `XX-X-X` and `XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-X` are both valid templates as long as there are the same number of X's as input characters.

So far I have this: `"/^([^a-zA-Z0-9]*X){9}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"` which will validate my template.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Is there a way to replace one matched character from the template with one character from the string?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?  Depending on the engine, it might be easier to go outside regex to do it.

Comment: PHP and C++ both need to handle this.

Comment: If anyone needs regex help this is a great resource to play around with: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'll need to convert your simple template into REGEX and you can do this with REGEX:

I. **Create the replacement**:

- search regex `^X+(\W)X+(\W)X+$` replace with `\\1\1\\2\2\\3`
- this will transform `XXX-XXX-XXX` into `\1-\2-\3` [explained demo here](http://regex101.com/r/hZ6yT9)

II. **Create the match**: (two steps)

1. Create the three groups:

   - search regex `^(X+)\W(X+)\W(X+)$` replace with `(\1)(\2)(\3)`
   - this will transform `XXX-XXX-XXX` into `(XXX)(XXX)(XXX)` [explained demo here](http://regex101.com/r/fW6mJ3)
2. Replace the `X`'s with dots (`.` acts as a single character match), over the above operation

   - this will transform `(XXX)(XXX)(XXX)` into `(...)(...)(...)` [explained demo here](http://regex101.com/r/oQ3fI6)

Now you can use your new Match string `(...)(...)(...)` and new Replacement string `\1-\2-\3` with the input string `ABCDEFGHI` and get `ABC-DEF-GHI` [explained demo here](http://regex101.com/r/yT5gZ6)

**Notice:** I'm assuming your template will split the input string into 3 parts with 2 *(variable)* special characters in between

### Update:

If the template has variable parts you have to create you *match* and *replacement* patterns in advance:
Use the regex: `\W` to **count** the parts in the template, then create your match and replacement patterns.

Comment: sorry my question didn't really specify but it will have to be able to cater for more than 3 groups as well and also more than 9 characters.